# If A holds reference to B, can B be garbage collected?

Tags: garbage-collection

This is actually a question for the book "Java Performance", where the author mentioned:

> Garbage collecting the young generation space prior to garbage collecting the old generation space usually results in less work for the garbage collector and more objects being garbage collected since objects in the old generation space may be holding object references to objects in the young generation space. **If the young generation space is not garbage collected, any object in the old generation space that holds a reference to an object in young generation space cannot be garbage collected.**

I feel the bold sentence is incorrect. I think he actually meant that, if the young generation space is not garbage collected, any object in the old generation space that **is referenced by(rather than holds a reference to)** an object in the young generation space cannot be garbage collected.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

> I think he actually meant that, if the young generation space is not garbage collected, any object in the old generation space that is referenced by(rather than holds a reference to) an object in the young generation space cannot be garbage collected.

I agree with you. Probably just a typo.